# How to import a class from a jar in a pojo generation from json

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo

I am using jsonschema2pojo to generate a pojo from a schema like the following:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema#",
    "type":"object",
    "name":"person",
    "description":"Details about the card to be tokenized.",
    "properties":{
        "name":{"type":"string"},
        "address":{
            "type":"object",
            "$ref":"common_components/address.json"
         },
    }
}
```

When I run jsonschema2pojo it generates two classes Person.java and Address.java under the same package.

The Pojo for Address also exists in the package generated for the common components.

My question is: is it possible that jsonschema2pojo generates Person.java using an import of the Pojo generated for Address under the common components package instead of generating a new Pojo?

Comment: Try setting the javaType property in the the address schema.  There are still some issues running around with $ref and you may be running into one of them.